# Score of importance from feature selection techniques

Tags: machine-learning, chi-squared-test, feature-selection, scikit-learn, mutual-information

Can I get the score of importance for each feature in feature selection methos such as Chi2, Information Gain (IG), or Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE)? Or they just provide a list of important features?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, in scikit-learn you can only get individual (relative) features importance if you're using an ensemble method of decision trees. After fitting a model you can check `model.feature_importances_`. As in the example below:

```
# Feature Importance
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
# load the iris datasets
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
# fit an Extra Trees model to the data
model = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model.fit(dataset.data, dataset.target)
# display the relative importance of each attribute
print(model.feature_importances_)
```

Source: https://machinelearningmastery.com/feature-selection-in-python-with-scikit-learn/

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810339/how-are-feature-importances-in-randomforestclassifier-determined) has also some more in-depth answers on the subject.

Comment: I don't think you are answering his question here, he is asking about specific feature importance algorithms not just if any exist.

Comment: @astel a matter of adverb. Fixed, thanks for speaking out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use scikit-learn so I can't speak to the specifics on that, but the R package CORElearn will give you importance values (usually on [0,1] I think) for features using information gain, minimum description length, and a whole host of others.  Might be of interest to check that package out if scikit-learn can't provide what you are seeking.